# Lyapunov function

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

My lecturer gave us the definition of a strong Lyapunov function. She then said that if $V$ is positive definite but $dV/dt$ is also positive definite (instead of negative definite) in a region containing an equilibrium point then the equilibrium point is unstable. If $dV/dt$ is positive definite can we conclude straightaway that the equilibrium point is unstable or do we also require $V$ being positive definite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No,  function $V$ cannot be arbitrary. Only $dV/dt\geq 0$ is not sufficient to prove that it the equilibrium is unstable. 
For example let the stable simple linear system
$$\dot{x}=-x$$
with 
$$V=-x^2$$
then
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=-x\dot{x}=x^2$$
which is positive definite.

Comment: Sorry, I think you've misunderstood the question. I was asking if we can find a function V such that $dV/dt$ is positive definite in a region containing an equilibrium point then is it true that the equilibrium point is unstable?

Comment: @user152440 Well this is equivalent. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score -2):

No you do not require $V$ to be positive definite.
Read the [instability theorem by Chetaev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chetaev_instability_theorem)